# How to prove that insert complexity in binary search tree is minimum O(log n)?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

Is it connected to BST search O(log n) or height log n?

How to prove that insert will give give you correct BST in minimum O(log n) time?

Answer (score 2):

Insert complexity in a binary search tree is *not* minimum $\Omega(\log n)$. For instance, if the element to be inserted is larger than the largest element of the tree, then you can make the whole tree the left child of a new root node containing the element to be inserted.

In a *balanced* binary search tree, with only a pointer to the root and not any other nodes, I'd guess insert complexity is $\Omega(\log n)$. In order to prove this, you'd probabaly want to specify which type of balanced BST we're talking about: AVL, red-black, weight balanced, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal height of a BST is always log n, you can easily prove it by induction. Then if you want to insert a new node you need to find the corresponding leaf where to insert it, which takes at least log n operations (comparisons) in the worst case, more if the tree is not balanced (larger height). Hence you obtain an insert cost of O(log n). We always focus on the worst case scenario to compute the O-complexity.